# Why won't apk install in BlueStacks?

Tags: android, vue.js, apk, quasar-framework, bluestacks

Please suggest.
I have a project on vue quasar
I want to create an apk application and run it through bluestacks
The device emulator works correctly.
1.start the project using the command quasar build -m cordova -T android
[image]

The only warning is from Gradle about the version
[image]

Then I ran gradle --warning-mode all to understand the reasons.
The result is on the screenshot above.

Next, I drop the created apk into bluestaks, but it gives an error The application is not installed, it looks like the package is damaged.
I don’t understand just what is worth paying attention to? why not install or compile incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. The reason it wouldn't install was the apk not being signed.

you have to use keytool to generate a keystore first.
keytool is located in your java jdk folder the following example will generate a keystore. I would suggest running the command where you want to store the keystore for example from c:\dev\android\keys\

Note: you may have to type the full path to run keytool, and jarsigner. or add the jdk bin folder to your system paths

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore myquasar-release-key.keystore -alias myquasar-release -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 20000
```

after creating the keystore you have to sign the apk with jarsigner which also comes with the java jdk

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore c:\dev\android\keys\myquasar-release-key.keystore app-release-unsigned.apk myquasar-release
```

To finish up we need to run zipalign this will generate the final apk file. zipalign comes with the android sdk when installing android studio.

```
C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\versionnumber\zipalign -v 4 app-release-unsigned.apk myquasar.signed.apk
```

After doing these three steps you can now install on your phone/bluestacks/etc.  while installing you may get a warning that play-protect does not recognize the organization. This is fine since you built the apk you know where it came from.
On a side note. if you upload to google play. You must use the same keystore every time you update your app.

A guide showing this off with a simple application can be found here https://www.kevin7.net/post_detail/use-quasar-to-build-an-android-app